# Connect an android application (as client) and an application running on my machine (as server) via socket

Tags: java, android, sockets

I'm trying to create a communication via socket between an android app (it would be as client) and a java application (as server) running on my computer. Although my application is very simple, it crashes on my Android device.
Can anyone help me??? I will report below pieces of code..

SERVER-SIDE

```
  public class Server {
  public static void main(String args[]){
    try {
      ServerSocket ss=new ServerSocket(9090);
      Socket client=ss.accept();
      System.out.println("A request is arrived");
      ObjectOutputStream oos=new ObjectOutputStream(client.getOutputStream());
      PrintWriter out=new PrintWriter(oos,true);
      out.write("Hello..I'm the Server");
      out.flush(); out.close(); client.close();
        } catch(Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}
      }
   }
```

CLIENT-SIDE

```
  public class ChildActivity extends Activity{
  public static final int SERVERPORT = 9090;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_child);
    Button b=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            try {
                InetAddress addre=InetAddress.getByName("a.b.c.d"); //ip address got typing command ipconfig in windows
                Socket socket=new Socket(addre,9090);
                ObjectInputStream in=new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
                String msg=(String) in.readObject();
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), msg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                in.close();
                 } catch (Exception e) {e.printStackTrace();} 


                }
        }
    });... and so on }}
```

I've also included following permissions in file Manifest, because my phone is connected on the Internet via wi-fi.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
```

Every kind of help is well appreciated... Thanks again. 
ps. sorry for my English :P

Comment: We can't help without the stack trace from logcat.  That tells you **exactly** where the problem is but my guess is `networkOnMainThreadException`.

Answer (score 0):

I'll try to guess your crashlog. You have a android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException.

This answer should help you https://stackoverflow.com/a/6343299/1173794

Answer (score 0):

You are most propably getting a "No-Network-On-Main-Thread" exception.
Android doesn't permit you to do IO on the main thread because this blocks the UI and can lead to an application not responding screen. You could use an AsyncTask to do the IO in the background.